# View with gradient shadow

Tags: android, xml, android-view, shadow

I've been searching for a way to do something like a very simple CSS box-shadow for a view, just like a white paper on a grey background, with the white view having a gradient shadow.

I have already tried to use the attribute:

`android:elevation="Xdp"`

with a background set, but it's not working. I've tried a lot of solutions but none of them was working.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Cardview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:translationZ="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey_100">
```

And dont forget dependency

```
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
```

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for.